# no video formats found while using pafy

Tags: python, youtube-dl, pafy

```
player = vlc.Instance()
media_player = player.media_player_new()
vid = None
inp = input(">>>")


def readurl(query):

    url=  findurl(query)
    video = pafy.new(url)
    best = video.getbest()
    playurl = best.url
    Instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = Instance.media_player_new()
    Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
    Media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(Media)
    player.play()

readurl(inp)
```

When i run this program and i give it an input it prints out an ERROR: No video formats found.

I know that there is a problem with youtube-dl but pafy uses it and i wonder if there is a work around it, or at least if i can somehow make pafy use the yt-dlp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Youtube Audio Stream with yt\_dlp, NOT using pafy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893626/getting-youtube-audio-stream-with-yt-dlp-not-using-pafy)